# How to search array of object in backbone js

Tags: backbone.js

how to search array of object in backbone js.The collection contain persons model.

```
 [{
        name: "John",
        age: "18",
        likes: {
            food: "pizza",
            drinks: "something",
        }
     },
     ......
    ]
```

how can i get persons who likes something.
i did try `collection.where({likes :{food : "pizza"}});`

Answer (score 0):

Since your `food` property is in an object on the Person's attributes, using `where` (which by default just looks at the flat attributes) isn't going to work.  You can use the `filter` method to apply a truth test to all of the items in your collection and just get the ones that pass.

In the code you posted, it doesn't look like you have a Backbone [Collection](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection) proper, just a regular array of objects.

Since Underscore is on the page, you can use it to help filter through your list.

```
var people =  [
   {
      name: "John",
      age: "18",
      likes: {
         food: "pizza",
         drinks: "something",
      }
   },
   ......
];

var likesPizza = _.filter(people, function(person) {
   return person.likes.food === "pizza";
});
```

If it is in fact a Backbone Collection, you can use

```
this.collection.filter(people, function(person) {
   return person.get('likes').food === "pizza";
});
```